# Problems with fractions in a square root

Tags: spacing, fractions

whenever i have a fraction inside a square root, the square root symbol drops down below the line and intercepts whatever is on the next line.  I think the package savetrees may be causing the problem.

MWE

```
\[
  \begin{array}{ll}
    \sqrt{\frac{1}{x}}  &  \\
    intercepted text    &   \\ 
  \end{array}
\]
```

[image: Figure 1]

these are the warnings i get

```
Typesetting problem in main.tex (line 36): Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 36--41
Typesetting problem in main.tex (line 55): Overfull \hbox (16.36372pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 55--68
Typesetting problem in main.tex (line 53): Overfull \hbox (5.0pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 53--69
Typesetting problem in main.tex (line 87): Overfull \hbox (77.67256pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 87--97
Typesetting problem in main.tex: Overfull \vbox (27.9158pt too high) has occurred while \output is active []
```

Comment: You can control the vertical space using `\\[1em]` for example. Also you don't need to break the line for the last line.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem, especially since I don't see the problem you are reporting when I make a complete document.  Hence there must be some other package/setting that is causing this problem.

Comment: I think the package that may be causing the problem is savetrees.

Comment: Thanks for posting a screen shot. Unfortunately, the code snippet you've provided does not, by itself, give rise to the very deep bottom of the square root sign. Please post a full MWE that generates the problem illustrated in the screen shot.

Comment: @user50375 Unfortunately, `savetrees` by itself is not the problem (I just did a test and couldn't reproduce the odd behaviour). As others have suggested, we'll need a MWE.

Comment: Also a math mode problem, because `intercepted text` is set in text, not math mode. Are there any errors compiling the document?

Comment: I'm trying to build a MWE but its not working very well.  The document has few warnings...

Comment: my MWE I made is not producing the error, even though i have copied the entire heading of my main file over to the MWE.  I moved a chunk of code that was producing the error in my main file up to the top to see if it still produced the error, and it did.  im not sure what else to do at this point.

Answer (score 3):

When inside an `array` environment, LaTeX is in so-called inline-math mode, meaning (among other things) that the vertical space between lines is deliberately kept to a minimum. (Incidentally, I cannot replicate the look of the screen shot you've provided based solely on the code snippet you've provided. When I expand the code snippet into a reasonably minimalist compilable LaTeX document, the bottom of the square root symbol does not literally intersect the material in the next line: TeX adds some emergency vertical space to keep this from happening. Have you -- or a package loaded in the preamble -- fiddled with the parameters that govern the insertion of emergency vertical stretch?)

To lessen the appearance of such a (near-)intersection, you could manually add a bit of vertical space to the row that contains the term `\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}}`. Or, to incorporate the fact that LaTeX is in inline-math mode while inside an `array`, you could choose to switch to "inline fraction look", i.e., write `\sqrt{1/x}` instead of `\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}}`. If the `amsmath` package is loaded, you could compact the expression further by writing `\sqrt{\smash[b]{1/x}}`; the `[b]` part tells TeX not consider any material that drops below the baseline when deciding how low the bottom part of the square root sign should be set.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \text and \smash[b] macros
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{lll}
 \sqrt{\frac{1}{x}} & \sqrt{1/x} & \sqrt{\smash[b]{1/x}} \\
 \text{Almost intersects}  &\text{Doesn't intersect} &   \text{Doesn't intersect} \\ 
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for `\smash[b]{1/x}`. I never knew `\smash` had an optional argument.

Comment: @Casimir - It's the `amsmath` package that provides this extension/refinement of the TeX `\smash` macro.

Answer (score 2):

I propose a solution based on `cellspace` that lets you define a minimal vertical spacing between the top of a row and the bottom of the above row, and symmetrically between the bottom of a row and the top of the row below. All you have to do then for tabulars is to prefix the qualifier for the columns with the letter S (or C if you load `siunitx`).

For math, it's a little more complicated: first you have choose the `math` option; and for each column you have to ask enter mathmode. For some reason, the S qualifier makes leave math mode. So I define a new column type to save some typing. The code that follows illustrates this.

Note that solutions based on increasing the value of `\arraystretch` results in row contents that is not vertically centred.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[math]{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{4pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{4pt}
\newcolumntype{M}{ >{$}Sl <{$}}

\begin{document}

\[ \begin{array}{ll}
\hline
\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{x}}  &  \\
\hline\addlinespace
\text{intercepted text}    &  \\
\hline
\end{array}
\qquad
\begin{array}{ MM}
 \hline
\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{x}}  &  \\
\hline
\text{intercepted text}    &  \\
\hline
 \end{array} \] 
\end{document}
```

[image]